# Geometry Nodes: Is it possible to transfer an attribute from point cloud to instance?

Tags: geometry-nodes

One situation that I often encounter while making animations with geometry nodes is the transfer attributes from a point (in a point cloud) into an instance that's created using that point.

A typical scenario:

- On a base mesh (sometimes with sometimes without PointDistribute) I perform various calculations, so that now each point in the mesh (or point cloud created via PointDistribute) now contain some new attributes, for example phase (0-1) of the animation that I want each particular point to have.
- I use PointInstance to instantiate an object on that point cloud.
- I then want to use the "phase" attribute that I created in the point cloud, so that each newly created instance can "inherit" phase attribute from a point that's used to create that instance.

When in 3.00alpha AttributeTransfer node appeared I thought it would perform that function, but it doesn't. Any ideas? Should I explain the question better?
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's a missing functionality for now I'm afraid. I'm sure it will be added in a future version. AFAIK custom attributes are lost when using the point instance node

Comment: I want that too!!!!

Comment: Try this. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245007/is-there-a-way-to-transfer-an-attribute-value-from-a-point-to-the-instance-or-t

Answer (score 3):

Since 3.0 you can use the *Capture Attribute* node for this. Here is an example:

[image: node setup]

[image: result]