# Is there a way to transfer an attribute value from a point to the instance (or the "realized" vertices of the instance)?

Tags: modeling, instances, point-clouds, geometry-nodes

I have a curve with control points on which I'm going to instance spheres that are going to have shifting scale values (that is done) and hopefully shifting materials (and here I struggle).
So I managed to add an attribute value (see picture) to the control points (vertices of the curve) that will control the factor in my mix shader for the material.

The problem is how to transfer (or assign) this attribute Value that is currently assigned to these control points), to my spheres instances (or the vertices of the realized spheres) that I’m instancing on that control points?
Hopefully it’s clear what I’m trying to say. Thanks

[image]

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer". This will make it easier for others to see which path leads to the solution, and the question will no longer show as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

shader setup:

[image]

modifier:

[image]

result:

[image]

and if you add this little node here:

[image]

you get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This nice little trick only works if the objects all have the exact same number of vertices. I found this while searching for a solution, where I randomly pick different objects from a collection (using 'Collection Info'). In this case this cannot work. I guess there is no real solution for transferring attributes (e.g. the point index) from points to instances to realized objects(?)

Comment: just what was I looking for, awesome